# Saber el nombre del directorio en el que ejecuto un script powershell?

Tags: powershell

¿Cómo saber el nombre del directorio en el que ejecuto un script powershell?, mi código es el siguiente:

```
$usuario = $env:USERPROFILE

[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("$usuario\Desktop\"nombre de la carpeta"\lib.dll")
```

Quiero poner una variable en el "nombre de la carpeta" que me coja el nombre de la carpeta actual donde ejecuto el script como seria !!! he mirado con las variables de entorno pero no encuentro ninguna que me sirva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza la variable automática:

```
$PSScriptRoot
```

Dentro de un archivo `.ps1` te devolverá la ruta desde donde se encuentra el archivo `.ps1`